# Error en app compilada con expo React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, qrcode, expo

Tengo una consulta he compilado una app para escanear qr con expo y barcode-scanner. La aplicación anda perfecto pero despues de algunos escaneos me salta este error en los telefonos con android: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he logrado encontrar a que se debe este error. Se deberá al escaner o a otra cosa? Uso asyncStorage para guardar algunos datos. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco sobre el error que recibes y sin conocer nada acerca del código que usas:

Por un lado según la propia librería  ([Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/SystemSensorManager.java#162)) mSensorListeners  es un HashMap que almacena los listeners de la aplicación y su tamaño máximo es 128.

Por otro lado, es un error similar de una aplicación que lee códigos de barras  ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960236/how-can-i-avoid-exceeding-the-sensor-listener-size-with-barcodescanner-in-react))

Por último, en este hilo se aporta información respecto al funcionamiento de sensorListener ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269925/how-to-know-if-my-sensormanager-has-a-registered-sensor)). 
Inicialmente Pavel indica que el propio Android se encarga de evitar que se registre el mismo Listener 2 veces pero qrtLs  añade:

"SensorEventListeners pueden ser registrados múltiples veces" y recomienda hacer uso SENSOR_DELAY_GAME y THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND.

Finalmente hace mención a una recomendación de Google: 
"Los datos del sensor pueden cambiar a una velocidad muy alta, lo que significa que el sistema puede llamar al método onSensorChanged(SensorEvent) con bastante frecuencia. Como práctica recomendada, debe llamar lo menos posible a onSensorChanged(SensorEvent) para no bloquearlo. Si su aplicación requiere que filtre o reduzca los datos del sensor, debe realizar ese trabajo fuera del método onSensorChanged(SensorEvent)"

Espero que te sirva de ayuda